# React router v4 - route with params renders blank page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm trying to implement React Router v4 in my create-react-app app and my routes work except for the route with an /:id parameter as it just renders a blank page. I've searched for 2 days and tried implementing the solutions [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/333#issuecomment-326834151) which says to add `<base href="/" />` to the head section of index.html and I've also tried following this [Medium guide for simple routing](https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf) but it still does not work. I don't understand, what is going on?

My code is below, any help is greatly appreciated!

Index.js

```
ReactDOM.render((
<BrowserRouter>
    <App />
</BrowserRouter>), 
document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Routes />
    )
  }
}
```

Routes.js

```
export const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <main>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route exact path="/movies" component={Search} />
            </Switch>
        </main>
    );
}
```

Search.js

```
render() {
        let filteredMovies = this.state.movies.filter((movie) => {
            return movie.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        })

        return (
            <div>
                <p>Search Page</p>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.updateSearch}/>
                </form>
                <div>
                    {filteredMovies.map((movie, idx) => 
                        <div>
                            <div key={idx}>
                                <Link to={`/movies/${movie.videoId}`}>
                                    <img src={movie.image.high.url} height="160px" width="100px" alt=""/>
                                    <p>{movie.title}</p>
                                    <p>{movie.quality}</p>
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/movies/:id" component={Single} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default Search;
```

Single.js

```
class Single extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Single Movie...</p>
                {this.props.match.params.id}
            </div>
        )
    }
} 

export default withRouter(Single);
```

Every route works except for /movies/:id where it just renders a completely blank page. It doesn't even show the `<p>Single Movie...</p>`.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `exact` from route that corresponds to `Search` component in your `Routes`, i. e.:

```
export const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <main>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/movies" component={Search} />
            </Switch>
        </main>
    );
}
```

The explanation is pretty simple: the `exact` prop means that your component will render only if current route is exactly the same as you specified in the `path` prop

---

### Update

If you want to render the list of movies only when no `:id` is specified, you should render your list in `Switch`:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/movies" render={props => {
        return (
            <div>
                {filteredMovies.map((movie, idx) => 
                    <div>
                        <div key={idx}>
                            <Link to={`/movies/${movie.videoId}`}>
                                <img src={movie.image.high.url} height="160px" width="100px" alt=""/>
                                <p>{movie.title}</p>
                                <p>{movie.quality}</p>
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    } />
    <Route path="/movies/:id" component={Single} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: I took off the `exact` portion and now it renders the `Single` component at the bottom of the entire list of movies instead of on a completely new page. The list is approx 300 items so how do I render to a completely new page instead of having to scroll all the way down to see the the `Single` component at the bottom of the list?

Comment: Thanks it worked! I was going to ask why, but I found that `<Switch>` renders the route exclusively so that explains it.

Comment: @RBenn the trick is that ```Switch``` renders exactly one route from list of routes inside it (well, it works like a default JS ```switch () {...}``` operator) :3